# Como poner espacios vacios

Tags: javascript, espacio-de-nombres

No entiendo como poner espacios vacios. Os enseño ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Las " " + turtle... no lo entiendo. En la consola al poner estas cosas salen leonardo ... con espacios pero si pongo un espacio solamente normal como esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
EN la consola salen las turtles sin espacios. NO LO ENTIENDO, necesito ayuda gracias

Ayuda solamente gracias

Comment: Saludos, por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/608780/edit) y agrega el código y la salida de la consola en formato de texto, solo utiliza imágenes cuando sea absolutamente necesario. ;)

Comment: Se le llama **concatenar**. Tienes que usar las comillas y el signo + `" " + variable` para que se interprete literalmente que se va a agregar un espacio vacío antes de la variable. Esto no funciona ` variable` porque no estás **concatenando** nada a la variable, solo estás pasando el valor de la variable. También puedes usar **template literals**, pero te dejo el concepto para que lo estudies por tu cuenta.